# Merge multiple lists containing same element in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Trying to figure it out, how can I merge output like this one in Prolog:

```
[[z], [l, e, d], [j, i, d, c, a], [g, f, b], [h, b]]
```

to get result:

```
[z]

[l,e,d,j,i,c,a]

[g,f,b,h]
```

Not sure how to merge multiple lists containing at least one similar character.

I would appreciate any help from more experienced guys, cause I am just beginner and this task is quite tricky.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Task is to get from edges defined by user all connected components and print them on output.

For instance user input edges:

```
data([[z,z],[a,c],[c,d],[d,i],[i,j],[d,e],[e,l],[b,f],[f,g],[b,h]]).
```

So I'm trying to figure it out how to solve this problem.
What I've just did:

```
data(Edges):-
    dbH(Edges),
    searching,
    print,
    retractall(e(_,_)),
    retractall(lists(_)).

dbH([]).
dbH([[X, Y] | Body ]) :-
    assertz(e(X,Y)),
    dbH(Body).

oe(X,Y):-
    e(X,Y);
    e(Y,X).

searching:-
    nextE.

searching([Act | RouteStartAct]):-
    nextE([Act | RouteStartAct]).

nextE:-
    oe(Act,New),!,
    delE(Act,New),
    cycle([Act],New).
nextE:-
    !.

nextE([Act | RouteStartAct]):-
    oe(Act,New),!,
    delE(Act,New),
    cycle([Act | RouteStartAct],New).
nextE(Act):-
    assertz(lists(Act)),
    searching.

delE(X,Y):-
    retract(e(X,Y));
    retract(e(Y,X)).

cycle(Act,New):-
    not(mbr(New, Act)), !,
    searching([New|Act]).
cycle(Act,New):-
    assertz(lists(Act)),
    searching.

mbr(Element, [Element|_]).
mbr(Element, [_|Body]) :- 
    mbr(Element, Body).

print:-
    findall(C,lists(C),L),
    write(L).
```

At the end write(L) prints list of lists which I need to further merge based on the similar elements in each list. Like connect parts of one graph together and print them.

**EDIT2**
The result of this command:

```
?- data([[a, c], [c, d], [d, i], [i, j], [d, e], [e, l], [b, f], [f, g], [b, h]]).
```

is

```
[[j, i, d, c, a], [l, e, d], [g, f, b], [h, b]]
```

so from this output is obvious, that list `[j, i, d, c, a]` and `[l, e, d]` can be merged into one list `[j, i, d, c, a, l, e]`. Same for the lists  `[g, f, b]` and `[h, b]`, these two lists have common character `b` , so the output should be `[g, f, b, h]`.
As a result of these two merges final output should look like:

```
[j, i, d, c, a, l, e]

[g, f, b, h]
```

Is it more obvious know?

Comment: You need to show what  you have tried even if does not work and explain what you intended it to do and what it did instead. Questions without this typically don't get answers. In other words it looks like a homework problem an most people don't give answers to homework, only help.

Comment: Thanks for response, you're right. What I can do is to compare two lists (A and B) and if there is one similar character in list B from list A, then I can join these two lists together, but what if there is no connection at all? Leave them as they are, but what if there are other 10 lists to compare? Numerous of lists complicated situation for me...

Comment: Can you show the expected answer for the input given. At present I would have to guess.

Comment: You have to join only consecutive lists or `A` and `B` can be not consecutive? I mean: what do you want from `data([[a, b], [d], [b, c]])`? `[[a, b, c], [d]]` or `[[a, b], [d], [b, c]]`? Anyway, if you can show us the expected answer from the given input can be helpfull.

Comment: "...get all connected components". What do you mean by "component"?

Comment: Thanks guys for quick responses. I created EDIT2, so know I hope that my situation is clearer? My idea is to merge multiple lists (more than two) containing common character as well as print lists without any common character. @max66 to answer your question:  `data([[a, b], [d], [b, c]])? [[a, b, c], [d]]` could be acceptable output. The second output  `[[a, b], [d], [b, c]]` is not a good result hence list `[a, b]` and `[b, c]` can be merged because both lists share common character `b`.

Comment: @lurker , sorry for bad explanation. Not a native speaker...by expression "connected components" is meant that user input represents edges of some disconnected graph and I want to find paths among these edges and then print nodes which are connected. As it is disconnected graph there could exist more than one path and therefore the output should count with it and print all isolated subgraphs. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with

```
touching(A,B):- memberchk(E,A), memberchk(E,B).

joined(A,B,C):- touching(A,B), setof(X, (member(X,A) ; member(X,B)), C).
```

Now you are left with the task of formulating a step relation which will find *any* two members of a given list for which `touching/2` succeeds, and update the list with the new `joined/3` entry; and repeat this step until it can't be performed any more; thus arriving at the solution.

Comment: I love your use of `setof/3` here! s(X)

Comment: Looks perfect, I need to slightly edit you advice and add some things, but hope it solves my problem. Big thanks Will !!!

Comment: @DanielLyons I tried everything else first though. :) it didn't work for some reason. (bagof did not remove the duplicates... don't understand why).

Comment: @OndrejFranek you are very welcome. the thing is, first we need to get to the working solution; only *then* we ought to start thinking about optimizing it.

Comment: I'll look at it closely tomorrow after couple of days staring into monitor I need some rest to be fresh for final move :_).

Comment: @WillNess The only difference between `setof/3` and `bagof/3` is that `setof/3` gives you _unique_ results for `Goal` and `bagof/3` gives you _every_ result for `Goal`. So that's exactly why it works, you're trying to get the _set_ of common values! :)

Comment: @DanielLyons ah, you're right, thank you! was thinking bag is a set *conceptually*, that's what threw me off. haven't used one in a while. :|

Answer (score 0):

@WillNess Hi again Will, I've spent another day trying to implement your hint to my situation, but unfortunately I am not able to rework your source in order to work properly for my case. Especially I strungle with situation when I need to use recursion to operate through all lists and if I find that two lists have at least one similar element I can join them together through setof function and continue with this new list to compare rest. However what first two lists dont have any similar element? Giving an example: `[[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g],[i,j,k],[e,a,b]]`. In this situation if I try to compare list `[a,b,c,d]` and `[e,f,g]` then I give fail to connect these two lists together, because they dont have any similar character. But at the end after connection `[a,b,c,d]` and `[e,a,b]` I am able to connect also the first situation `[a,b,c,d]` and `[e,f,g]`. Can you see my point? I need to somehow iterate from one way and back as well. This kind of situation is absolutely dead end for me. Wondering if there is better solution to my main goal which is print all parts of disconnected graph based on the edges inserted by the user.

Comment: hi. (a) according to SO guidelines you really should ask this as another question, giving a link back to this one for context. (b) yes, I see your point; what I suggested would work exactly that way; though I only gave you a qualitative outlook so to speak, i.e. what I show will only show you there's some pair that's touching, but it won't give you those two elements -- this specific predicate you need to code, still. It'd give you back, presumably, the two touching elements and the rest of them, so you can prepend the joined segment back with the rest of them. So, please delete this A and ask

Comment: So, please delete this answer and ask a new question. Your new code will use `touching` and `joined`, but you still have to do the `picking` so to speak. And the reason I answer you so late is, that the @ referrals do not work in the answers, only in the comments. So I didn't get pinged and saw your comment only by chance. :) You really should delete this question, otherwise it might get closed by  moderator as "not an answer".